# ¿Como quitar caracteres que no sean letras de Regex en python?

Tags: python, regex

Necesito poder tener nada mas letras de la a a la z minusculas y mayusculas con la ñ incluida, la cosa esta en que necesito que todo lo que no sea letra que se ponga despues lo descarte.
Tengo esto:

```
patronATOM=re.compile(r'\~?[a-zA-Z\u00F1\u00D1]')
```

Pero esto nada mas valida que haya puesto letras al inicio, si le pongo por ejemplo un | %#%/ etc lo toma como bueno, intente quitar eso con esto:

```
patronATOM=re.compile(r'\~?[a-zA-Z\u00F1\u00D1]\W?!')
```

Pero ya no me acepta nada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo arregle, lo unico que hice fue añadirle el operador ^ y +$ y validar los codigos \u00F1\u00D1 de ñ y acento respectivamente. El ^ y $ indica que tanto al inicio como al final, solo quiero lo de adentro de las llaves, el + antes del $, indica que es forzoso que haya eso, el completo es:

```
patronATOM=re.compile(r'^\~?[a-zA-Z\u00F1\u00D1]+$')
```

Comment: No me deja aceptar mi propia respuesta hasta dentro de dos dias, en dos dias lo hago.

Comment: Si bien tu respuesta (la expresión regular) es correcta, tu explicación no acaba de serlo. `+$` todo junto no es ningún operador. `^` y `$` no apuntan o referencian a las llaves/corchetes y `+` no hace obligatorio nada, es un quantizador

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza lo siguiente `^~?[a-zA-Z\u00F1\u00D1]+$`

```
^        # Inicio de línea
    ~?   # El caracter ~ puede estar 0 o más veces
    [    # Inicio de 'clase' con posibles caracteres
      a-zA-Z\u00F1\u00D1
    ]+   # la clase se puede repetir una o más veces
$        # Después, debe venir un final de línea
```

**Notas:**

- El caracter `~` no es especial, así que no necesitas escaparlo con contrabarra
- `^` y `$` no apuntan a nada, pero el hecho de que en tu expresión regular especifiques que inicia con principio de línea, termina con final de línea y especifiques lo que hay en medio, hace que funcione de manera global. Pero este uso de `^` y `$` no es el único posible ni tienen porque aparecer ambos a la vez. Por ejemplo, una expresión regular que encuentre todas las letras 'a' que tienen de seguido una 'b' o fin de línea podría ser: `ab|a$`
- El caracter `+` es un quantizador. Indica que lo anterior debe repetirse una o más veces. No hace obligatorio nada. Las cosas son obligatorias por el mero hecho de haberse escrito (a menos que hayamos utilizado algo como `?` o `{0,}` donde podrían ser opcionales